# How does one access DataGrip in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, datagrip

It sounds like JetBrains "DataGrip" functionality is included with PhpStorm. (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000877044-DataGrip-FAQ). How does one access the DataGrip functionality from within PhpStorm? (For example I want to explore a sqlite/mysql database)

Is this the same as the "Database Navigator" plugin? (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"DataGrip functionality" incudes:

- Database toolwindow (Data Sources/DB connections, viewing DB structure)
- Query console (edit and execute SQL statements)
- Table/Query results viewer
- Import into/Export from DB
- DB diagrams
- Search for DB objects from Search Everywhere
- etc

You can check the following links from the PhpStorm Help and PhpStorm website:

1. Video overview (quite old, but still valid): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjPbxVlPnSI
2. Introduction blog post (very old): https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/11/sql-support-and-database-tools/
3. Database tools and SQL (main entry): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/relational-databases.html

   - Connecting to SQLite DB: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sqlite-database
4. Database tool window: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/database-tool-window.html
5. Query console: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/query-console.html

Comment: this video is datagrip-related, but pretty fresh and all described there is included in PhpStorm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5SOD-eeK50